# How to use google geococde api in Java

Tags: java, geocoding

Is this correct?
I am trying to understand it but I am not getting how timezones work in general or in this api, also why timestamp is required as a query to get a timezone of a perticular location?
Please help.

Comment: please refer [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2015/09/geocoding-api-google-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation, it clearly says the following that answers you question

Required Parameters

***- timestamp***

specifies the desired time as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. The Google Maps Time Zone API uses the timestamp to determine whether or not Daylight Savings should be applied. Times before 1970 can be expressed as negative values.

It is taken from documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro